# python inheritence call new url after overriding

Tags: python

In the following code even after overiding the init function it still calls the old url,i want the new url contents instead how to do this

```
  import urllib
  import json


  class process():
     def processdata(self):
        for di in results:

           super(processcontent,self).__init__(new_url)
           new_obj  = getcontent.getdata()
           print new_obj
           break



  if __name__ == '__main__':
     url = "someurl"
     p = processcontent(url)
     #print p.getdata()
     p.processdata()
```

Comment: Are you stuck with the class design or can you change it as there are much easier ways to do what you want?

Comment: By the way, the first parameter to classmethod `getdata(self)` is not a class instance, it's the class itself, and the parameter is thus usually called `cls`. Also, as @PadraicCunningham mentioned, you should probably rethink your class design a bit IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not call `__init__` after initialization, second,  you don't use the attribute `self.url` but the global variable `url`.
Since `url` isn't a real attribute, you should call `getdata` with a parameter `url`:

```
  import urllib
  import json



  class processcontent(Basecontent,getcontent):
     def processdata(self):
        obj = self.getdata(self.url)
        results = obj["response"]
        for di in results:
           new_url =  di["clusterUrl"]
           new_obj  = self.getdata(new_url)
           print new_obj
           break

  def main():
     url = "someurl"
     p = processcontent(url)
     #print p.getdata()
     p.processdata()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: One question, is staticmethod better or using a classmethod in the above case

Comment: since you don't use `cls` you can convert it to a static method.

Answer (score -1):

```
 class getcontent(object):
     @classmethod
     def getdata(self):
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)  #  <--- module-level variable
        content = json.loads(response.read())
        return content
```

You are referencing a module-level variable `url` in your `getdata()` method.